# SQL - query request

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Basically I have two tables entitled `Purchase` and `PurchaseRefund`.

You can have one `Purchase` but multiple `PurchaseRefund` rows based on the `PurchaseId`.

What I am trying to do is write a query taking the parameters `@purchase_id` and `@refund_id`

Let's say we have a purchase row which has a `TotalAmount` of £10 and `SubTotal` of £10

Then we have two `PurchaseRefund` rows ....

```
216 - Has a refundAmount of £2.50   
217 - Has a refundAmount of £2.25
```

Therefore, when the query runs with `@refund_id` as **216** it should show

```
SubTotal: £10  
Refund: £2.5  
Total: £7.50
```

And when the query runs with `@refund_id` as **217** it should show

```
SubTotal: £7.50  
Refund: £2.25  
Total: £5.25
```

I hope that makes sense

Comment: What you're looking for is running totals. You can do this using self joins and a host of other methods. Bing and ye shall seek.

Comment: Raj - does this help  pastebin.com/t3mhHKQt

Comment: can I assume refund_ID is linear in relation to time and that you only want to show those totals equal to or less than the refund_id being looked for?

Comment: XQbert - yes on both accounts, this might help you  pastebin.com/t3mhHKQt

Answer (score 1):

You need to join from `Purchase` into `PurchaseRefund` and get all rows that "match" your criteria - something like:

```
DECLARE @Purchase TABLE (PurchaseID INT, TotalAmount DECIMAL(10,2))

INSERT INTO @Purchase VALUES(42, 10.0)

DECLARE @PurchaseRefund TABLE (RefundID INT, PurchaseID INT, RefundAmount DECIMAL(10,2))

INSERT INTO @PurchaseRefund VALUES (216, 42, 2.50)
INSERT INTO @PurchaseRefund VALUES (217, 42, 2.25)

DECLARE @MaxRefundID INT = 217

SELECT 
   p.PurchaseID,
   SUM(r.RefundAmount) AS 'Refund', 
   MAX(p.TotalAmount) - SUM(r.RefundAmount)  AS 'Total'
FROM @Purchase p
INNER JOIN @PurchaseRefund r ON p.PurchaseID = r.PurchaseID
WHERE r.RefundId <= @MaxRefundID
GROUP BY p.PurchaseID
```

This works mostly OK - for a value of `@MaxRefundID = 216` I get:

```
PurchaseID  Refund  Total
   42        2.50   7.50
```

and for a value of `@MaxRefundID = 217` I get:

```
PurchaseID  Refund  Total
  42         4.75   5.25
```

Comment: That is close dude although the Refund for 217 should show 2.25

Comment: @user1052764: yeah, I know you've asked for that- can't wrap my head around how to achieve this :-( My solution will just *sum up* all the refunds up to and including that ID you're giving....

Answer (score 0):

If this is for a display / report, I'd do the running totals in that, doing it with sql is a massive PIA.

```
SELECT 
p.Amount,
r.Refund,  
Sum(rPrevious.Refunds) As RunningTotal,
FROM Purchases p
Inner Join Refunds r On r.PurchaseId = p.PurchaseID And r.RefundID = @RefundID
Inner Join Refunds rPrevious on r.PurchaseID = p.PurchaseID AND rPrevious.RefundID < @RefundID
WHERE p.PurchaseID = @PurchaseID
Group By p.Amount,r.Refund
```

Would give you for 216
10,2.50,0
and
10,2.25,2.5 for 217 so

```
Select (Amount - RunningTotal) as Subtotal,
Refund, 
(Amount - Refund - RunningTotal) as Total
From
( SELECT 
  p.Amount,
  r.Refund  
  Sum(rPrevious.Refunds) As RunningTotal,
  FROM Purchases p
  Inner Join Refunds r On r.PurchaseId = p.PurchaseID And r.RefundID = @RefundID
  Inner Join Refunds rPrevious on rPrevious on r.PurchaseID = p.PurchaseID 
                                  AND rPrevious.RefundID < @RefundID
  WHERE p.PurchaseID = @PurchaseID
  Group By p.Amount,r.Refund
) RunningTotals
```

Should do the job, not checked though and I might have taken a bit of a license with your column names.

Theory is sound though the row you want is
Purchase amount - Sum of refunds < @RefundID
The amount of the refund for refundid
and your total is just one - the other. Or purchase Amount - Sum of Refunds **<=** @RefundID

The inner query trick just saved a lots of arsing about getting the sum of refunds up ? twice, once for subtotal and once for total.

**Missing parenthesis added...**

Comment: Hi Tony,

My query is this - http://pastebin.com/P0HTf3XT

But I get the following error:

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near 'RunningTotals'.

Comment: Hm, I don't have priveleges to edit; looks like you need a close parentheses in first line of that second code block.

Comment: Missimg comma as well ARGGHHH!

Answer (score 0):

This builds on marc_s's solution to get the exact numbers your looking for.

```
DECLARE @Purchase TABLE (PurchaseID INT, TotalAmount DECIMAL(10,2))

INSERT INTO @Purchase VALUES(42, 10.0)

DECLARE @PurchaseRefund TABLE (RefundID INT, PurchaseID INT, RefundAmount DECIMAL(10,2))

INSERT INTO @PurchaseRefund VALUES (216, 42, 2.50)
INSERT INTO @PurchaseRefund VALUES (217, 42, 2.25)

DECLARE @RefundID int = 217

SELECT 
   p.TotalAmount - (SELECT SUM(RefundAmount) FROM @PurchaseRefund WHERE RefundID < r.RefundID) as SubTotal,
   r.RefundAmount AS 'Refund', 
   p.TotalAmount - (SELECT SUM(RefundAmount) FROM @PurchaseRefund WHERE RefundID <= r.RefundID) as Total
FROM @Purchase p
INNER JOIN @PurchaseRefund r ON p.PurchaseID = r.PurchaseID
where r.RefundID = @RefundID
GROUP BY r.RefundID, p.TotalAmount, r.RefundAmount
```

Comment: This is kind of right although for RefundId - 217 the SubTotal is wrong as its displaying 10 instead of 7.50

Answer (score 0):

Managed to work it out its probably not the best but it works ....

```
DECLARE     @subtotal                                       DECIMAL(18,2)


SELECT      @subtotal                                       = COALESCE  (SUM(PurchaseRefund.RefundAmount), 0) 
                                                            FROM        PurchaseRefund 
                                                            WHERE       PurchaseId      = @PurchaseId 
                                                            AND         id              < @PurchaseRefundId


SELECT          pure.Id, 
                pure.ConsumerId, 
                pure.ConsumerCode, 
                pure.RetailerStoreId,
                pure.RefundAmount, 
                pure.TimestampReceived, 
                pure.TimestampPayPalRequest, 
                pure.TimestampPayPalResponse, 
                pure.TimestampResponed          AS TimestampResponded, 
                pure.RefundKey, 
                pure.ResponseCode, 
                pure.RetailerId,
                reco.Headline                   AS OfferUsed,
                retr.Name                       AS RetailerName,
                rest.Name                       AS RetailerStoreName,
                purc.CurrencyCode,
                reco.DiscountType,
                reco.DiscountValue,
                purc.PayKey,
                purc.TransactionId,
                2                                           AS transactionType,
                purc.isInStore,
                purc.Total - @subtotal                      AS SubTotal, 
                purc.Total - @subtotal - pure.RefundAmount  AS Total, 
                purc.TrackingId, 
                purc.ResponseCode, 
                pure.TerminalId,
                pure.Id                     AS PurchaseRefundId,
                purc.Id                     AS PurchaseId       

FROM            PurchaseRefund              pure

INNER JOIN      Purchase                    purc
ON              pure.PurchaseId             = purc.Id

INNER JOIN      Retailer                    retr
ON              purc.RetailerId             = retr.Id

LEFT OUTER JOIN RetailerCoupon              reco
ON              purc.RetailerCouponId       = reco.Id

LEFT OUTER JOIN RetailerStore               rest
ON              purc.RetailerStoreId        = rest.id

WHERE           purc.Id                     = @PurchaseId
AND             pure.Id                     = @PurchaseRefundId
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT purchase.id, purchase.amount, sum(purchaseRefund.amount), (purchase.amount - sum(purchaseRefund.amount)) as total
FROM Purchase as purchase
LEFT JOIN PurchaseRefund as purchaseRefund on purchaseRefund.purchaseId = purchase.id
WHERE purchase.id = 216
```

Comment: Thorsten - cheers for the help much appreciated. However returns an error message

Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Column 'Purchase.Id' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.